# Why does my Jupyter notebook shows two pythons?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am having trouble understanding this. Inside a Jypyter notebook I run these commands. Shouldn't these two have the same result?

I changed the kernel on the notebook to ENV, the virtual environment. So any system calls should be made with the virtual environment, right?

```
import sys
sys.executable

'/usr/bin/python'
```

Yet,

```
!which python

'/home/user/ENV/bin/python'
```